# AES-GCM for file encryption in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I am trying to use AES-GCM encryption for file encryption in python. I am using `Cryptodome` package and I know exactly what to do to perform encryption/decryption using `encrypt_and_digest` and `decrypt_and_verify` on a single plaintext string based on [this example](https://github.com/wolf43/AES-GCM-example/blob/master/aes_gcm.py). 
Now, I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a text file. It contains multiple AES blocks and I want to check the authentication tag at the beginning of the decryption process to verify the integrity of the file. I cannot figure out how to generate a single authentication tag for the whole file and verify it in the destination. Currently, I have the following code:

**Encryption**

```
def encrypt(self, filename):
    iv = get_random_bytes(16)
    cipher = AES.new(self.K4, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as src:
            with open(filename + ".enc", 'wb') as des:
                des.write(iv)
                for block in iter(lambda: src.read(AES.block_size * 128), b''):
                    if len(block) == AES.block_size * 128:
                        des.write(cipher.encrypt(block))

                    # Padding the last block
                    else:
                        remain = len(block) % 16
                        if remain == 0:
                            remain = 16
                        block += utility.to_bytes((chr(remain) * remain))
                        des.write(cipher.encrypt(block))
    except (IOError, OSError):
        raise IOError("Cannot open the file to encrypt")
```

**Decryption**

```
def decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        try:
            with open(ciphertext, 'rb') as src:
                with open(ciphertext.strip(".enc") + ".dec", 'wb+') as des:
                    iv = src.read(16)
                    cipher = AES.new(self.K4, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
                    for block in iter(lambda: src.read(AES.block_size * 128), b''):
                        des.write(cipher.decrypt(block))

                    # Remove padding
                    # Set the pos to the beginning of the last byte
                    des.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
                    # Read the last byte
                    last = des.read(1)
                    des.seek(-int.from_bytes(last, byteorder='big'), os.SEEK_END)
                    des.truncate()
        except (IOError, OSError):
            raise IOError("Cannot open the file to decrypt")
```

As you can clearly see, there are no authentication verification performed. Any idea?

Comment: Here's the [`encrypt_and_digest()`](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/7acba5f3a6ff10f1424c309d0d34d2b713233019/lib/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py#L983) source, if you were having trouble finding it.

Comment: @glibdud I found the source. But the problem is that I can only get a tag for each block of the file. Should I generate a tag for each block and verify each block tag at the destination? I assume there must be a way to generate a single authentication tag for the whole file.

Comment: You can't verify the integrity of the file until the *end* of the decryption process.